# How to generate random numbers with predefined probability distribution?

Tags: python, numpy, probability, probability-density, probability-distribution

I would like to implement a function in python (using `numpy`) that takes a mathematical function (for ex. `p(x) = e^(-x)` like below) as input and generates random numbers, that are distributed according to that mathematical-function's probability distribution. And I need to plot them, so we can see the distribution.

I need actually exactly a random number generator function for exactly the following 2 mathematical functions as input, but if it could take other functions, why not:

1) `p(x) = e^(-x)`
2) `g(x) = (1/sqrt(2*pi)) * e^(-(x^2)/2)`

Does anyone have any idea how this is doable in python?

Comment: Numpy has a number of distribution methods built in: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/routines.random.html#distributions

Comment: Second one should be valid over all numbers, since the normalization constant is 2pi

Comment: [This](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/577264-random-numbers-with-arbitrary-probability-distribu/) link and the first comment under that post might help.

Comment: *"...that takes a `f(x)` as input ..."*  What is `f(x)`, and what does it have to do with the two functions `p(x)` that you show?

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser i meant "a function" (not f(x)) as argument (input). The 2 p(x)'s are the mathematical functions that I want to use the python function for, which are as explained above: ".... and generates random numbers, that are distributed according to the following probability distribution function:" But you are right. It is a bit ambigious, and the 2 p(x)'s should have been named differently.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

For simple distributions like the ones you need, or if you have an easy to invert in closed form CDF, you can find plenty of samplers in NumPy as correctly pointed out in Olivier's answer.

For arbitrary distributions you could use Markov-Chain Montecarlo sampling methods.

The simplest and maybe easier to understand variant of these algorithms is [Metropolis](https://aip.scitation.org/doi/abs/10.1063/1.1699114) sampling.

The basic idea goes like this:

- start from a random point `x` and take a random step `xnew = x + delta`
- evaluate the desired probability distribution in the starting point `p(x)` and in the new one `p(xnew)`
- if the new point is more probable `p(xnew)/p(x) >= 1` accept the move
- if the new point is less probable randomly decide whether to accept or reject depending on how probable<sup>1</sup> the new point is
- new step from this point and repeat the cycle

It can be shown, see e.g. [Sokal](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/978-1-4899-0319-8_6)<sup>2</sup>, that points sampled with this method follow the acceptance probability distribution.

An extensive implementation of Montecarlo methods in Python can be found in the [`PyMC3`](http://docs.pymc.io/notebooks/getting_started) package.

## Example implementation

Here's a toy example just to show you the basic idea, not meant in any way as a reference implementation. Please refer to mature packages for any serious work.

```
def uniform_proposal(x, delta=2.0):
    return np.random.uniform(x - delta, x + delta)

def metropolis_sampler(p, nsamples, proposal=uniform_proposal):
    x = 1 # start somewhere

    for i in range(nsamples):
        trial = proposal(x) # random neighbour from the proposal distribution
        acceptance = p(trial)/p(x)

        # accept the move conditionally
        if np.random.uniform() < acceptance:
            x = trial

        yield x
```

Let's see if it works with some simple distributions

### Gaussian mixture

```
def gaussian(x, mu, sigma):
    return 1./sigma/np.sqrt(2*np.pi)*np.exp(-((x-mu)**2)/2./sigma/sigma)

p = lambda x: gaussian(x, 1, 0.3) + gaussian(x, -1, 0.1) + gaussian(x, 3, 0.2)
samples = list(metropolis_sampler(p, 100000))
```

[image: metropolis gaussians sum]

### Cauchy

```
def cauchy(x, mu, gamma):
    return 1./(np.pi*gamma*(1.+((x-mu)/gamma)**2))

p = lambda x: cauchy(x, -2, 0.5)
samples = list(metropolis_sampler(p, 100000))
```

[image: metropolis cauchy]

### Arbitrary functions

You don't really have to sample from proper probability distributions. You might just have to enforce a limited domain where to sample your random steps<sup>3</sup>

```
p = lambda x: np.sqrt(x)
samples = list(metropolis_sampler(p, 100000, domain=(0, 10)))
```

[image: metropolis sqrt]

```
p = lambda x: (np.sin(x)/x)**2
samples = list(metropolis_sampler(p, 100000, domain=(-4*np.pi, 4*np.pi)))
```

[image: metropolis sinc]

### Conclusions

There is still way too much to say, about proposal distributions, convergence, correlation, efficiency, applications, Bayesian formalism, other MCMC samplers, etc.
I don't think this is the proper place and there is plenty of much better material than what I could write here available online.

---

1. The idea here is to favor exploration where the probability is higher but still look at low probability regions as they might lead to other peaks. Fundamental is the choice of the *proposal* distribution, i.e. how you pick new points to explore. Too small steps might constrain you to a limited area of your distribution, too big could lead to a very inefficient exploration.
2. Physics oriented. Bayesian formalism (Metropolis-Hastings) is preferred these days but IMHO it's a little harder to grasp for beginners. There are plenty of tutorials available online, see e.g. [this one](http://people.duke.edu/~ccc14/sta-663-2016/16A_MCMC.html#Why-does-Metropolis-Hastings-work?) from Duke university.
3. Implementation not shown not to add too much confusion, but it's straightforward you just have to wrap trial steps at the domain edges or make the desired function go to zero outside the domain.

Comment: thanks for the great answer! Just a question, how can I plot the code as you did to get that plots? Could you please add the code used for plotting? And what is burnin? Thx!

Comment: First samples in a markov chain are usually highly correlated so it's a good practice to discard them, especially if you need just a few points. Burn-in is the number of samples to drop. My plots are histograms done with `plt.hist(samples, bins=100)`.

Comment: @ZelelB by the way, if you just need exponentials, normals and other simple distributions, Metropolis is not the way to go. Using numpy samplers is a lot safer than baking your own like this, especially as I left out a lot of details about writing good montecarlo code (there's lots of pitfalls to be aware of when working with random numbers).

Comment: actually burn-in is not really needed here, I'll remove it as it adds unnecessary confusion

Comment: Nm, I misunderstood the problem; this approach is fine.

Comment: @filippo I think your solution is quite what I need, because it is an assignment, and we cannot use the predefined numpy & scipy libraries which are going to get it done in one line. But I am skeptical about the metropolis. I don't know if I have to use it.

Comment: @ZelelB I thought so. If you didn't cover Montecarlo methods in the course then Metropolis is not what you're supposed to use. You most probably have to use some CDF inversion method to transform uniform samples (see the bottom of Olivier's answer). For normal distributions you can use Box-Muller which is really easy to implement (see e.g. [this tutorial](https://glowingpython.blogspot.com/2013/01/box-muller-transformation.html)). There are plenty of other well known transformations you could use, Cauchy samples can be generated from normal pairs for example.

Comment: But the thing is: Ok, for the first function, I got it, it is a gaussian distribution, and setting a=1/2pi , mu=0 and sigma=1 you get it. But what is the second function? How to implement it like you did with the gaussian one?

Comment: @filippo the solution with the domain isn't working. It is throwing an exception, as the domain isn't in the metropolis_sampler's signature. Do you know how I can fix it?

Comment: @ZelelB there's a note about domain, the easiest way is to define your `p` function so that it returns `0` outside the domain you want. I believe there's plenty of material here, between Oliver's answer, mine and comments, to get you started on your assignment

Comment: @filippo thank you so much for the great answer! Just last two questions: What is actually the delta=2.0 in the uniform_proposal mathematically? Is it the step of the walk that we try or what exactly? And what are the values of the y-axis on the plots? for example by on your last example plot the (2k, 4k, 6k, 8k)? Is it the Nr. of times, the generator runned? I mean the nr of iterations?

Comment: @ZelelB it's an histogram, you divide your domain in a number of bins and count how many samples each bin contains. So you have `bins` for `x` and `counts` for `y`. `delta` is the maximum distance your walker can explore at each step. `2.0` there is quite arbitrary, there are theoretical considerations that relate it to the variance of the peak you're exploring but for simple use cases you just need it to be empirically big enough for the walker not to be trapped in a high probability region and properly explore all the space

Comment: Thank you so much for all this help! Very helpful and such a great answer!

Comment: This is a fantastic guide. I'm looking for a way to store distributions as objects based on some starting data. These objects should be able to be added together too. My thought was to estimate and store a bandwidth parameter, and use it with a KDE which could be used to generate data as per your answer. If two distributions need to be added, then I just add their two KDEs with their two stored bandwidth estimates, and sample from that. Or create a new bandwidth estimate from concatenating a sampling of both. Unfortunately I have to do all this in Java :(

Answer (score 6):

NumPy offers [a wide range of probability distributions](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/routines.random.html#distributions).

The first function is an [*exponential distribution*](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.random.exponential.html#numpy.random.exponential) with parameter 1.

```
np.random.exponential(1)
```

The second one is a [*normal distribution*](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.random.normal.html#numpy.random.normal) with mean 0 and variance 1.

```
np.random.normal(0, 1)
```

Note that in both case, the arguments are optional as these are the default values for these distributions.

As a sidenote, you can also find those distributions in the `random` module as `random.expovariate` and `random.gauss` respectively.

### More general distributions

While NumPy will likely cover all your needs, remember that you can always compute the inverse [cumulative distribution function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cumulative_distribution_function) of your distribution and input values from a [*uniform distribution*](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.random.uniform.html#numpy.random.uniform).

```
inverse_cdf(np.random.uniform())
```

By example if NumPy did not provide the *exponential distribution*, you could do this.

```
def exponential():
    return -np.log(-np.random.uniform())
```

If you encounter distributions which CDF is not easy to compute, then consider [filippo's great answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51057365/5079316).

Comment: The first one is most likely the exponential distribution with `beta=1`, and should have the domain restricted to [0, inf), in which case it is a true probability distribution

Comment: @filippo I am not familiar with that algorithm, if you were to provide an example as answer I would be interested

Comment: @OlivierMelançon thank you for your detailed answer! But I don't really get how to use that to implement my python function, so that it takes for example the given p(x) or g(x) as input, and generates random numbers distributed according to them. And is it possible to plot the result then? So that a visual explanation is there?

Comment: I think I need to use something like here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution#Generating_values_from_normal_distribution, but I am weak to implement it!

Comment: @ZelelB Have a look at filippo's great answer. Using sympy you could convert the strings to functions, then use Metropolis sampling.

Answer (score 3):

In the past few years, nice new tools have been added to SciPy to address this kind of problem in Python.
You can easily generate samples from **custom continuous or discrete univariate distributions** by just providing some information about the distribution, such as the density / pdf. The methods rely on numerical inversion of the distribution function or on the rejection method.

Overview of the different methods:
https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/stats.sampling.html

Tutorial:
https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/tutorial/stats/sampling.html

These methods are designed for univariate distributions. **I do not recommend to use the Metropolis algorithm in that setting**: the main drawback is that it generated **correlated** samples whereas these methods give you independent samples. The Metrolpolis algorithm can be helpful if you want to sample from multivariate distributions, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metropolis%E2%80%93Hastings_algorithm for the advantages and disadvantages)

Here is a simple example how you can use an inversion method from SciPy:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats.sampling import NumericalInversePolynomial
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from scipy.integrate import quad


class MyDist:
    def __init__(self, a):
        self.a = a

    def support(self):
        # distribution restricted to 0, 5, can be changed as needed
        return (0, 5)

    def pdf(self, x):
        # this is not a proper pdf, the normalizing
        # constant is missing (does not integrate to one)
        return x * (x + np.sin(5*x) + 2) * np.exp(-x**self.a)


dist = MyDist(0.5)
gen = NumericalInversePolynomial(dist)

# compute the missing normalizing constant to plot the pdf
const_pdf = quad(dist.pdf, *dist.support())[0]

r = gen.rvs(size=50000)
x = np.linspace(r.min(), r.max(), 500)

# show histogram together with the pdf
plt.plot(x, dist.pdf(x) / const_pdf)
plt.hist(r, density=True, bins=100)
plt.show()
```

[image: Pdf and histogram of the samples]