# Generate a random number according to a specific distribution with a function

Tags: python

I am trying to generate a random number in Python according to a precise distribution that I define with a `function f (theta) = 1 + alpha*cos(theta)²`; the variable alpha is a constant.

Unfortunately I do not know how to do it because the different random functions all follow a pre-defined distribution (normal, uniform, binomial ...)

Have you got an idea?

Comment: What is the range of theta?

Comment: In general, you can subclass the `rv_continous` class from scipy.stats package. But your function doesn't obviously met conditions of either cumulative distribution function (cdf) or probability distribution function (pdf). To be a valid pdf function it should have AUC (area under the curve) equal 1, To be a valid cdf function it should be at least non-decreasing function.

Comment: @gmds theta is defined under 0 and pi

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to generate random numbers with predefined probability distribution?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51050658/how-to-generate-random-numbers-with-predefined-probability-distribution)

Comment: In addition to the duplicate question, see also my article on [sampling a number with an arbitrary distribution](https://peteroupc.github.io/randomfunc.html#Random_Numbers_from_an_Arbitrary_Distribution), which also includes Python sample code that implements this approach, notably the `numbers_from_pdf` method.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the density function you have is proportional to a probability density function (PDF) you can use the *rejection sampling* method: Draw a number in a box until the box falls within the density function. In this case, the density function is `64/(99*math.pi)` and its maximum value is `1+alpha`.

For code that implements rejection sampling, see the following answer of mine:

- [Random numbers with user-defined continuous probability distribution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66874819/random-numbers-with-user-defined-continuous-probability-distribution/66875719#66875719)