# Getting random numbers from a truncated Maxwell-Boltzmann distribution

Tags: python, random, scipy, montecarlo

I would like to generate random numbers using a truncated Maxwell-Boltzmann distribution. I know that scipy has built-in Maxwell random variables, but there is no truncated version of it (I am also aware of a truncated normal distribution, which is irrelevant here). I have tried to write my own random variables using rvs_continuous:

```
import scipy.stats as st

class maxwell_boltzmann_pdf(st.rv_continuous):

    def _pdf(self,x):
        n_0 = np.power(np.pi,3/2)*np.square(v_0)*(v_0*erf(v_esc/v_0)-(2/np.sqrt(np.pi))*v_esc*np.exp(-np.square(v_esc/v_0)))
        return (1/n_0)*(4*np.pi*np.square(x))*np.exp(-np.square(x/v_0))*np.heaviside(v_esc-x,0)

maxwell_boltzmann_cv = maxwell_boltzmann_pdf(a=0, b=v_esc, name='maxwell_boltzmann_pdf')
```

This does exactly what I want, but it is way too slow for my purpose (I am doing Monte Carlo simulations), even if I draw all the random velocities outside of all the loops. I have also thought of using Inverse transform sampling method, but the inverse of the CDF does not have an analytic form and I will need to do a bisection for every number I draw. It would be great if there is a convenient way for me to generate random numbers from a truncated Maxwell-Boltzmann distribution with decent speed.

Comment: What are typical ranges for the parameters?

Comment: I am using v_0 = 220 km/s and v_esc = 550 km/s

Comment: Are those the only values you're using for v_0 and v_esc?

Comment: Yes (at least for the current simulation I am working on)!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that there is a way to generate a truncated Maxwell-Boltzmann distribution with the inverse transform sampling method using the ppf feature of scipy. I am posting the code here for future reference.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from scipy.special import erf
from scipy.stats import maxwell

# parameters
v_0 = 220 #km/s
v_esc = 550 #km/s
N = 10000

# CDF(v_esc)
cdf_v_esc = maxwell.cdf(v_esc,scale=v_0/np.sqrt(2))

# pdf for the distribution
def f_MB(v_mag):
    n_0 = np.power(np.pi,3/2)*np.square(v_0)*(v_0*erf(v_esc/v_0)-(2/np.sqrt(np.pi))*v_esc*np.exp(-np.square(v_esc/v_0)))
    return (1/n_0)*(4*np.pi*np.square(v_mag))*np.exp(-np.square(v_mag/v_0))*np.heaviside(v_esc-v_mag,0)

# plot the pdf
x = np.arange(600)
y = [f_MB(i) for i in x]
plt.plot(x,y,label='pdf')

# use inverse transform sampling to get the truncated Maxwell-Boltzmann distribution
sample = maxwell.ppf(np.random.rand(N)*cdf_v_esc,scale=v_0/np.sqrt(2))

# plot the histogram of the samples
plt.hist(sample,bins=100,histtype='step',density=True,label='histogram')
plt.xlabel('v_mag')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

This code generates the required random variables and compare its histogram with the analytic form of the pdf, which matches with each other pretty well.

Answer (score 1):

There are several things you can do here.

- For fixed parameters `v_esc` and `v_0`, `n_0` is a constant, so it doesn't need to be calculated in the `pdf` method.
- If you define only a PDF for a SciPy `rv_continuous` subclass, then the class's `rvs`, `mean`, and so on will be very slow, presumably because the method needs to integrate the PDF every time it needs to generate a random variate or calculate a statistic. If speed is at a premium, you will thus need to add to `maxwell_boltzmann_pdf` an `_rvs` method that uses its own sampler. (See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62516272).) One possible method is the *rejection sampling* method: Draw a number in a box until the box falls within the PDF. It works for any bounded PDF with a finite domain, as long as you know what the domain and bound are (the bound is the maximum value of `f` in the domain). See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55724501) for example Python code.
- If you know the distribution's CDF, then there are some additional tricks. One of them is the relatively new [*k-vector sampling*](https://arxiv.org/abs/2004.02339) method for sampling a continuous distribution. There are two phases: a setup phase and a sampling phase. The setup phase involves approximating the CDF's inverse via root finding, and the sampling phase uses this approximation to generate random numbers that follow the distribution in a very fast way without having to further evaluate the CDF. For a fixed distribution like this one, if you show me the CDF, I can precalculate the necessary data and the code needed to sample the distribution using that data. Essentially, the only non-trivial part of *k-vector sampling* is the root-finding step.
- More information on sampling from an arbitrary distribution is found on my [sampling methods page](https://peteroupc.github.io/randomfunc.html#Random_Numbers_from_an_Arbitrary_Distribution).