# Issues with Python scipy rv_continuous implementation

Tags: python, random, distribution, scipy.stats

I'm trying to create a subclass of rv_continuous with a custom distribution for which I can calculate the pdf through a number of functions.

Here's what I've done so far

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import rv_continuous
```

ancillary functions

```
def func1(xx, a_, b_, rho, m, sigma):
    return a_ + b_*(rho*(xx-m) + np.sqrt((xx-m)*(xx-m) + sigma*sigma))

def func2(xx, a_, b_, rho, m, sigma):
    sig2 = sigma*sigma
    return b_*(rho*np.sqrt((xx-m)*(xx-m)+sig2)+xx-m)/(np.sqrt((xx-m)*(xx-m)+sig2))

def func3(xx, a_, b_, rho, m, sigma):
    sig2 = sigma*sigma
    return b_*sig2/(np.sqrt((xx-m)*(xx-m)+sig2)*((xx-m)*(xx-m)+sig2))

def func4(xx, a_, b_, rho, m, sigma):
    w = func1(xx, a_, b_, rho, m, sigma)
    w1 = func2(xx, a_, b_, rho, m, sigma)
    w2 = func3(xx, a_, b_, rho, m, sigma)
    return (1.-0.5*xx*w1/w)*(1.0-0.5*xx*w1/w) - 0.25*w1*w1*(0.25 + 1./w) + 0.5*w2

def func5(xx, a_, b_, rho, m, sigma):
    vsqrt = np.sqrt(func1(xx, a_, b_, rho, m, sigma))
    return -xx/vsqrt - 0.5*vsqrt
```

density function eventually

```
def density(xx, a_, b_, rho, m, sigma):
    dm = func5(xx, a_, b_, rho, m, sigma)
    return func4(xx, a_, b_, rho, m, sigma)*np.exp(-0.5*dm*dm)/np.sqrt(2.*np.pi*func1(xx, a_, b_, rho, m, sigma))
```

a set of parameters

```
Params = 1.0073, 0.3401026, -0.8, 0.000830, 0.5109564
```

check the pdf from function

```
xmin, xmax, nbPoints = -10., 10., 2000
x_real = np.linspace(xmin, xmax, nbPoints)

den_from_func = density(x_real, *Params)
```

now construct my distribution class

```
class density_gen(rv_continuous):
    def _pdf(self, x, a_hat, b_hat, rho, m, sigma):
        return density(x, a_hat, b_hat, rho, m, sigma)
```

instantiation

```
my_density = density_gen(name='density_gen')

my_density.a, my_density.b, my_density.numargs
```

As I've specified _pdf I should have a working distribution instance

this works

```
pdf = my_density._pdf(x_real, *Params)
```

cdf works too albeit it's extremely slow

```
cdf = my_density._cdf(x_real, *Params)
my_density._cdf(0.1, *Params)
```

but for all the other methods I get nans, for instance

```
my_density.mean(*Params)    
my_density.ppf(0.01, *Params)
```

What I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: Can you generate random numbers with `rvs`?  If not, then this may be a limitation in SciPy, since I can generate random numbers just fine using your PDF in my own implementation of a PDF sampler.  Is the PDF you give, with that set of parameters (`Params`) and bounds (`xmin`, `max`), the only PDF your application will use?

Comment: No I can not. Tried my_density.rvs(100000, *Params) and got ValueError: Domain error in arguments. With my_density._rvs(100000, *Params) gives AttributeError: 'density_gen' object has no attribute '_size'. I can generate samples from the pdf with my own sampler too and then get a best fit with Scipy's distributions but I'd really like to have a working rv_continuous instance. I generate many sets of Params daily (possibly intraday) and for many cases, the pdfs can vary widely. Bounds too can change albeit to a lesser extent. So speed is a concern here. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears you need to add the [`_argcheck`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.rv_continuous.html#scipy.stats.rv_continuous) method to `density_gen`, since your distribution uses custom parameters:

```
class density_gen(rv_continuous):

    def _argcheck(self, *Params):
        return True

    def _pdf(self, x, a_hat, b_hat, rho, m, sigma):
        return density(x, a_hat, b_hat, rho, m, sigma)

my_density = density_gen(name='density_gen')
pdf = my_density._pdf(x_real, *Params)
print(my_density.rvs(size=5, *Params))
print(my_density.mean(*Params))  
print(my_density.ppf(0.01, *Params))
```

However, `rvs`, `mean`, and so on will then be very slow, presumably because the method needs to integrate the PDF every time it needs to generate a random number or calculate a statistic. If speed is at a premium, you will thus need to add to `density_gen` an `_rvs` method that uses its own sampler. An example of this is my own [`DensityInversionSampler`](https://github.com/peteroupc/peteroupc.github.io/blob/master/randomgen.py), which generates random numbers by numerical inversion, when given only the PDF and the sampling domain.

Comment: Understand, definitely would need to add more _methods if I wanted to use this in production.