# How do I generate numbers according to a parabolic distribution?

Tags: random, probability, probability-distribution

I have a function which plots the distribution of ions emitted as a function of the angle of emission. To simulate the emission I would like to sample values according to the function, but I'm struggling to do so.

The function is:
[image]

where theta_0 is a constant.

I've tried to use the inversion method, but I can't seem to get it to work.

Comment: Can you include some code with what you tried so far? You can also add a tag with the programming language/tools that you use.

Comment: Also, your question might be better suited for https://math.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I haven't actually got to the stage where I've used code for the problem yet, so you're probably right that I should post it on somewhere for maths. Thanks very much for the suggestion.

Comment: Is that supposed to be a density or a CDF? What's the range for Theta? What bounds are there for Theta_nought?

Comment: @pjs : `theta_0` is usually 18, according to the cross-post: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4567447/how-do-i-generate-numbers-according-to-a-parabolic-distribution

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66874819/random-numbers-with-user-defined-continuous-probability-distribution/66875719 .  It appears that the function above has a bounded domain [0, `theta_0`], and an upper bound of the maximum if `theta_0=18` is 82.

Comment: @PeterO. Still have no idea what the range of Theta is, nor whether this is a density or CDF. Makes a huge difference trying to set up a possible inversion.